# Laravel Eloquent whereHas. Несколько знчений в условии

Tags: php, laravel

Нужно отобрать склады, на которых есть все товары из списка.
Сейчас так (не очень красиво):

```
$storehouses=Storehouse::where('storehouses.user_id',$storeHouseUserId);
foreach($items as $productId)
{
   $storehouses=$storehouses->whereHas('products', function ($q) use ($productId)
        {$q->where('product_id',$productId);});
}
$result=$storehouses->orderByDesc('storehouses.extra_time_ship')->get();
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как облагородить этот кусок кода? Без использования цикла.
Код дает нужный результат.

Comment: `...->whereHas('products', fn ($q) => $q->whereIn('product_id', $items))...`

Comment: $q->whereIn('product_id', $items)
Так будет выбирать склады, на которых есть что-то из списка. А нужно все из списка (забрать все товары с одного склада).

Comment: Добавить можно в select() что-то типа DB::raw('COUNT(products.id) as products_count') + ->having('products_count', '=', count($items)), дебагбар ставьте и смотрите что быстрей работать будет

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю как то так, можно добиться тогоже без цикла

```php
$storehouses = Storehouse::where('storehouses.user_id', $storeHouseUserId)
    ->whereHas('products', function ($query) use ($items) {
        $query->whereIn('product_id', $items);
    })
    ->orderByDesc('storehouses.extra_time_ship')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Так будет выбирать склады, на которых есть что-то из списка. А нужно все из списка (забрать все товары с одного склада).